# How do I divide a 16 bit address bus between two chips

Tags: z80

I'm building (still in the planning/designing phase) an 8-bit computer around the Z84C0008 (it is just one of the newer generation Z80s, from my understanding.) I will have an AT28C64B EEPROM to load programs and maybe also hold some data for the long term at the lower 8 bits of the address bus and I will have 71256SA SRAM for the upper 8 bits of the address bus as RAM. I'm using a D-type flip flop to look at A15 and enable one of two chips. I know that I won't be able to use all the space in the chips, but their price played some role in my choice.  Smaller SRAMs are more expensive for some reason (maybe because they are made less.)

What I'm trying to get is, since I'm 'dividing' the address bus in half, am I really using the 64KBytes of space that Z84C0008 can address? I feel like because I'm only using 8 bits to address the memory chips, I'm actually only addressing 512 bytes (256 bytes per chip) of memory in total. Is it just my calculation that's horribly wrong and from the perspective of the Z84C0008, it doesn't matter? I am more inclined towards the latter but I'm not really sure, so I wanted to get the opinions of others.

Here is the circuit diagram. Please indicate if there is a mistake in it.

EDIT: My apologies. I messed up while explaining my connections. What I meant was that I will have the memory mapped such that EEPROM will have 0x000-0x7FFF and RAM will have 0x8000-0xFFFF. I don't know why I said I will connect them in an 8-bit + 8-bit way.

[image]

Comment: You're addressing 512 bytes in total. worse, you're addressing both chips at once. Address 1234 (hexadecimal) accesses address 12 on one chip and address 34 on the other chip, simultaneously. But that's for 8 bit chips. One of these chips has 12 bit addresses and the other has 15 bits so how's that going to work? Do you want to know how to do it properly?

Comment: Yeah, I had my doubts about the different number of addresses but I didn't think it'd be a problem as I'm planning to use only a part of it. That Flip-Flop at the top is supposed to enable one chip at a time, so I didn't think I would address both chips at once. This is my first attempt at doing something like this and yes, I'd like to learn to do it properly.

Comment: normally you would take A15 (for example) and wire it to /CS on one chip, and then to a NOT gate and wire the output of the NOT gate to /CS on the other chip. Then one chip is activated whenever A15 is 0, and the other chip is activated whenever A15 is 0. Not really sure why you would use a flip-flop

Comment: That's what I was going for by using the D Flip-Flop, except I tried to use the Q and /Q to enable/disable chips. I will change that to what you said. I'm happy to hear them if you have any other recommendations.

Comment: On your schematic you need to individually label all the address lines each place they come out of the bus - otherwise the CAD program won't know what is connected where.  The EEPROM should be enabled for the lowest part of the address space, as the processor will look at address 0x0000 for the first instruction after a reset.

Comment: Yes, that's where the EEPROM will be connected. I will have 0x0000-0x7FFF for EEPROM and 0x8000-0xFFFF for RAM. This diagram is not final and those are really there to give me an idea of where things go, I will edit it later.

Comment: Using a (D-type) flip-flop to select either (RA)Memory device is uncalled for: What do you plan to use for clock? You probably want it combined with ¬MREQ, anyway.

Comment: I did realise that after it was pointed out. As I said on other comments, I will be using the output of A15 with an inverter to get the signals needed and I will also be using the other pins of course, this circuit diagram is nowhere near being finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a 64k address bus, a 32k RAM and an 8k EEPROM. You're going to want the EEPROM mapped to the lower 8k of address space because in the Z80 CPUs execution starts at 0000h, so your boot code would start there. The RAM can map from 8000h to FFFFh. That leaves you with 24k of unused space. You might want to look at using that for I/O, extra RAM or extra EEPROM by dividing the lower 32k into four 8k blocks. For this you can use a 1 of 4 decoder like a 74x139 or CD4556.

Chip select (\$\small{\overline{CE}}\$) for the RAM would be \$\small\overline{A15}\$ and the decoder's chip select would be \$\small{A15}\$ so you would connect \$\small{A15}\$ to the decoder \$\small\overline{CE}\$ and through an inverter to RAM \$\small\overline{CE}\$.

\$\small{A13}\$ and \$\small{A14}\$ would go to the decoder A and B inputs, and you would now have four active low outputs to select 0000h to 1FFFh, 2000h to 3FFFh, 4000h to 5FFFh, and 6000h to 7FFFh. The first one would connect to the EEPROM \$\small\overline{CE}\$ and the others would be available for I/O or additional memory. Each of these blocks can be broken down further by adding decoders.

You may also have to use \$\small\overline{MREQ}\$ in the address decoding, I'm not super familiar with Z80, I mostly worked with 6502s. I would suggest having a look at [this site](http://www.z80.info/) as they have a lot of information including schematics for basic systems.

Comment: Thank you so much for your recommendations! I did realise that my EEPROM of choice was actually 8k and I will change that out for a 32k one. Since this is my first time actually designing and building something like this, I will keep it simple for now, but I will try out getting a smaller EEPROM and use the space for extra I/O or something else in my later iterations.

Comment: @aaamet I added a bit to my answer including a link to a site I think will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the link! Yes I will make use of other pins of course. This is the very beginning of the design so the circuit diagram is rather empty.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would take A15 (for example) and wire it to /CS on one chip, and then to a NOT gate and wire the output of the NOT gate to /CS on the other chip. Then one chip is activated whenever A15 is 0, and the other chip is activated whenever A15 is 1. Not really sure why you would use a flip-flop.

The address bits are wired to both chips (as many as possible). You don't divide the 16-bit address bus into 8 bits + 8 bits.

---

The purpose of the address bus is to tell you which address the processor wants to access. It is your job to make sure that when the processor accesses some address, it activates some chip and tells the chip some address, but they don't have to exactly match. For example, your EEPROM only has 13 address pins. Assuming you design it to access the EEPROM when A15=1, this means when the processor accesses address 8000 (hexadecimal) the EEPROM chip is activated and more specifically, address 0000 of the EEPROM chip is activated. When the processor accesses address 9FFF it activates the EEPROM chip address 1FFF. But when the processor accesses address A000, the EEPROM chip sees address 0000 again because the next address line isn't connected to the ROM. The processor's address output would be used like this:

```
   these bits don't do anything!
          | |
          V V
binary: 1 0 1 0   0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0
        |     |   | | | |   | | | |   | | | |
        V     V   V V V V   V V V V   V V V V
selects ROM   ---address to ROM chip (0000)---
instead of RAM
```

Since the ROM chip sees address 0000 it accesses the first byte of the ROM. That byte has 4 different addresses (8000, A000, C000 and E000) which secretly all point to the same byte.

The processor is completely fine with this. It doesn't know or care whether the same byte has more than one address. Think about it, it's the same as if you just copy-pasted the ROM data 4 times. All the processor knows is it asks for an address, and it gets some data.

It works for RAM too, by the way. However in your case you have 32 kilobytes of RAM so all the bits are used. If you had a smaller RAM you would have leftover address bits and you would have RAM mirroring.

---

Mirroring is okay because the Z80 is a rather simple processor with no built-in cache. If you would use a processor with a cache and you would mirror the RAM (let's say 8 kilobytes of RAM), that would be unsafe because the processor could cache address 0000 separately from 2000, thinking they were different. You could write them both, read them back and get two different data bytes... until one or both would get pushed out of the cache, at an unpredictable time, and then the processor would read them back from memory, and you'd get the same data twice. This would be totally unpredictable to you.

Note this is a hypothetical scenario that can't happen in the computer you are building.

It would be "unsafe" in the sense of causing unpredictable bugs and making you pull your hair out while trying to find the problem. It wouldn't blow up the processor, or anything like that.

And in this scenario you could easily avoid it by not using the mirrored memory. You would use address 0000-1FFF for your RAM, and not use 2000-7FFF, just like you wouldn't use them if they were unmapped.

Comment: Would the number of address pins need to be the same on every chip? I am going to wire address bits to each chip, but how would I need to configure them if they don't have the same number of address pins? I am struggling to find a through-hole memory chip that has 16 address bits. I am specifically looking for through-hole packages mostly for their added modularity with DIP sockets and the look I'm trying to achieve. This project is not that serious and I have no constraint on space or anything.

Comment: @aaamet how much do you know about address busses? What would be the effect if they were not all connected? let's say we have a 16-bit processor address bus and an 8-bit RAM chip (256 bytes) and the other 8 bits aren't connected. What happens when the processor accesses address 0000 (hex)? address 0001? address 0101?

Comment: If RAM is connected to the higher byte of the 16-bit address (A9-15), then the processor wouldn't access anything. At least from my understanding. I am only a student and this topic - to this much detail - is not within my curriculum, so all I really know is what I could understand by researching myself.

Comment: @aaamet: The 28C64 is only 8K - it should occuply addresses 0x0000 to 0x1fff.  The RAM could occupy addresses 0x8000 to 0xffff - this would leave a gap in the memory map - but that is not a problem.

Comment: Yeah, I got confused with the data sheet saying "64K (8K x 8)". Thank you so much for pointing that out :)

Comment: @PeterBennett with the obvious design (note I put ROM in A15=1 but I'm not sure which one aaamet actually needs) it occupies addresses 8000-9fff **and** a000-bfff **and** c000-dfff **and** e000-ffff. I wrote some more about this.

Comment: @aaamet That means there are 8K addresses and each one has 8 bits. There are (or were) also other memory layouts available. I seem to remember that early DRAM chips only had 1 data bit, so to get 8 bits, you'd have 8 of them and give them all the same address

Comment: @user253751: The Z80 looks at address 0x0000 after reset for the first instruction to execute, so EEPROM has to be at the bottom of memory, and the 32K RAM in the top half.  I agree that with simple address decoding the EEPROM will appear in four memory blocks.  Better decoding could allow four 8k eeproms in the bottom half of the memory.

Comment: @PeterBennett no need for that when you could make it a 32 kilobyte EEPROM and then everything fits very nice and neatly with no gaps, mirrors or other oddities.

Comment: I made a huge mistake while initially explaining how I wanted to have the memory mapped. What I meant was that I will have 0x0000 to 0x7FFF for EEPROM and 0x8000 to 0xFFFF for RAM. I don't how I mixed up having them mapped as such with having them connected 8 bit + 8 bit. And yes, I will change the EEPROM to have a 32KByte one.

Comment: My question now is: Is it okay if I connect them from A0-A14 and have A15 only for enabling/disabling chips since I only have 32KByte memory in each chip?

Comment: @aaamet why do you think it might be a problem?

Comment: I do not think it will be a problem. My intention in asking that was to look for a second opinion to make sure that I didn't miss a detail - which I do often enough - and that my thinking was right.

Comment: @aaamet The CPU only cares about one address at a time. It doesn't care how the chips are hooked up, as long as it can output an address and then read or write data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for their suggestions. First of all, I actually picked a 32KByte EEPROM now instead of an 8KByte one. I will connect all the address pins of both EEPROM and the RAM to the address pins on Z80 and I'm using an inverter to get the Chip Enable signals instead of a D-Type Flip-Flop. EEPROM will have the locations 0x0000 to 0x7FFF and RAM will have 0x8000 to 0xFFFF.

I have not touched on other pins like MREQ or so but of course, I will use them, my confusion was to do with memory chips and their connection.